Undefined predefind Bulma SASS color variable
When I was using Bulma 0.9.4 I could customise colors using Bulma's predefined colors e.g. something like this:
$body-background-color: $grey

With Bulma 1.0.1 I have code like the following:
@use "../bulma-1.0.1/sass/utilities" with (
    $body-background-color: $grey
);

but when I compile it with SASS I get the following error:
Error: Undefined variable.
 ╷
2│     $body-background-color: $grey
 │                             ^^^^^
make: *** [scss] Error 65

I can set $body-background-color to a literal color, or a Bulma predefined CSS variable but not a predefined SASS variable.
I hope I can get some guidance on how the @use commands work and why some of the variables come up as undefined.
Thanks in advance.
P.S. Cross posted as an issue on the Bulma's GitHub page: https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/issues/3859
